# Populate child dropdowns from a XML file by Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax

I have three dropdowns:

- Country
- State
- City

When I select a value in the Country dropdown, it should show the States of the selected country. When I select a value in the State dropdown, it should show the Cities of the selected state.

All data is available in a XML file. I would like to populate the child dropdowns using Ajax and PHP. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Search for it... or try something yourself and ask again if you have specific question. Or hire someone who is doing the job for you. This is website is for answering *specific* programming related question, it is not a *programming service*.

Comment: Don't ask for code directly. That isn't going to work here. State a problem and ask how to solve it. I have swept your "question". Nicer would be if you show *something* what you've as far and elaboare at what point exactly you're stucking. E.g. "How to read XML file into an array?", etc.

Answer (score 1):

You will essentially need a PHP script that handles the AJAX requests that populate the dropdowns. This script will accept parameters for Country and State and return the respective States and Cities respectively by parsing the appropriate XML file.

You will need to send an AJAX request at the `onchange` method of the dropdowns. The PHP script can return the results as a JSON object which your JS framework can access to modify the values of the dropdowns.

You should be able to find code that will do this by Googling. If you have any trouble with getting it to work, ask here!

Comment: You don't need a PHP-script. You can populate and modify the lists using JavaScript only.

Comment: This is true, but he has specifically stated that he would like to do this using a PHP script to parse the XMLs.

Comment: @Fareesh Vijayarangam, My apologies. I revoked my -1.

Comment: thanks for answer but i m facing prob to get particular cities from XML can any one share complete code of XML or javascipt

Comment: hey every one, still i m facing prob, i getting all countries from Xml and onchange events of Drop down menu i m getting selected country but prob is i can't get perticular cities of selected country.
i m using javascpt, ajax and XML or php